# How to remove elastic index with special characters in name?

Tags: elasticsearch

On an  an elasticsearch 2.2 node I accidentally created an index with the name '%{[index]}'.
How can this index be removed?

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/%{[index]}/'
```

fails with `curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 28`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to URL-encode the special characters in the index name, like this, and you index will magically disappear:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/%25%7B%5Bindex%5D%7D/'
```